# In Three20, can I not use custom table cells in a searchViewController?

Tags: iphone, three20, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I'm implementing a TTTableViewController with a searchViewController part, and I'm running into issues when displaying the results of the search in the search's TableView.

If I add TTTableTextItems to the datasource `items` property, it works fine, but if I try to add a TTTableCaptionItem or a TTTableImageItem or any custom cell I've created, the rendering is messed up.

Can anyone confirm that it's possible to use custom table cells in a searchViewController and perhaps point me in the right direction for how to make it work?

I've attached 3 screen shot to show what's working and what's not working.

**No. 1: Works with this code:**

```
[self.items addObject:[TTTableTextItem itemWithText:[item objectForKey:@"title"]]];
```

[image: TTTableTextItem]

**No 2. Breaks the layout with this code:**

```
[self.items addObject:[TTTableCaptionItem itemWithText:[item objectForKey:@"title"]
                                               caption:[item objectForKey:@"excerpt"]]];
```

[image: TTTableCaptionItem]

**No. 3 Also breaks the layout with this code:**

```
[self.items addObject:[TTTableImageItem itemWithText:[item objectForKey:@"title"]
                                            imageURL:[item objectForKey:@"thumbnail"]]];
```

[image: TTTableImageItem]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I figured it out. The key is setting the the `variableHeightRows` property to `YES` in the TTTableViewController that you're using as the search controller. Below is the code I've used.

```
TTTableViewController* searchController = [[[TTTableViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
searchController.dataSource = [[[MagazineSearchDataSource alloc] init] autorelease];   
searchController.variableHeightRows = YES;

self.searchViewController = searchController;
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = _searchController.searchBar;
```